# Is messaging library asynchronous while it is imported into C application?

Tags: c, rabbitmq, zeromq

Is ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ asynchronous, even when it is utilized in C programming?

Comment: Ehm - what? How is the programming language (presuming a turing complete, not a DSL) even related to synchronisation concepts? Does the C standard contain **any** timing behaviour for an implementation?

Comment: @Olaf ZeroMQ and RabbitMQ offer client APIs in various languages. This post is asking about the C client's specific capabilities. It's only unclear if you don't know what ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both ZeroMQ and RabbitMQ support asynchronous modes of operation, and this applies to the C client library implementations for both (as of this writing).